# How to mount a Synology NAS to keep permissions and modification dates?

Tags: mount, nas

Which is the best protocol to use to mount a recent Synology NAS ([DS1522+](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS1522+)) as root in Ubuntu 22.04 to then add a folder for each user and be able to run a cron job to cancel all files older than a certain date?

Basically I am looking to a sort of "storage extension" for a lab computational server, where permissions and modification dates are retained.
The NAS is on the same switch as the server.

EDIT:
What I would like to achieve is a FS like:

```
/home/user1
 - foo       (on the server HD)
 - nastemp   (on the NAS, symlink to /mountednas/user1)
/home/user2
 - goo       (on the server HD)
 - nastemp   (on the NAS, symlink to /mountednas/user2)
[...]
```

But I don't want to manage users on the NAS, only on the server.
`nastemp` are temporary folders where my users can store stuff for their ongoing individual projects and are deleted after 6 months.
Ideally the nas mount happens at boot time (e.g. on `/etc/fstab`) and symlinks are created in a script (`adduser.local`).

Comment: *as root (...) to then add a folder for each user* makes no sense and can't be done with a NAS.

Comment: are you talking about creating an iscsi volume on the NAS that you can use as a server hard disk?

Comment: I am looking at iSCSI, but it looks overcomplicated.. all I need is to mount a remote filesystem where I can set permissions for the server users

Comment: So if you are wanting to mount an SMB or NFS share, note that you will need to administer permissions on the NAS for objects within the share, rather than doing it through the server. The server OS doesn't really control the directories you mount on it, and has to rely on the NAS configuration for access control. Additionally since the server is using the sharing protocol to perform operations, it is the NAS that will be responsible for timestamping, not the server. thats the attractive thing about iscsi is that the disk filesystem is fully managed by the server.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes iSCSI would be more opportune I think, but it seems that NFS is also fine enought for my needs... I have created a shared folder in the NAS and created what it looks an ip based permission on it, so I can mount from the server just with a  `mount [NAS_IP]:volume1/compserver /mnt/nas2` and then I see I can chown/chmod the folders and these permissions are retained within different mounts. As this NAS folder is used only by the server, I am fine with it...  Now I need to check if this solution is ok for symlinks, large files, is fast enought..